# Where do I check if user have already logged in when app starts?

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, view

I need to know that so I won't push home UIView Controller (where users decide to log in or create a new account) but the App UIview Controller per se.

Comment: You could always save a CoreData object for the created user, and then when the application opens again, fetch from CD to see if the user is there or not.

Comment: I meant, where should I do that? appDelegate? anyothe config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fetching from CoreData, you can put it in the AppDelegate to determine the first view controller.

```
// Following method intimates us the application launched  successfully 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 

    // ***perform CoreData fetch here***

    NSString *nibName;
    if (/* created acct already */) {
        nibName = @"acctCreatedNib";
    }
    else {
        nibName = @"createNewAcctNib";
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @c_rath, despite I don't use nibs in my app since I work with storyboard, this was really useful. I just need to determine the initial view controller and then instantiate it with storyboard ID. I can't summit any vote to your answer because I'm a newbie in points. Have a good day